# How to divide a column into groups and loop across the groups

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column with IDs and I divide the column into groups using pd.cut like this:

| ID | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 3645390 | 1 |
| 3678122 | 1 |
| 3615370 | 2 |
| 3371122 | 2 |
| 3645590 | 2 |
| 3778682 | 3 |
| 3125140 | 3 |
| 3578772 | 3 |

After that, how do I loop across the 'Group' column and pick out the IDs and assign them to an array.

```
array_1 = [3645390,3678122]
array_2 = [3615370,3371122,3645590]
.
so on..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is often a bad practice to generate variables, the ideal is to use a container (dictionaries are ideal).

You could use `groupby` and transform the output into dictionary of lists:

```
out = df.groupby('Group')['ID'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Then access your lists by group key:

```
>>> out
{1: [3645390, 3678122],
 2: [3615370, 3371122, 3645590],
 3: [3778682, 3125140, 3578772]}

>>> out[1]  ## group #1
[3645390, 3678122]
```

If you really want `array_x` as keys:

```
(df.assign(Group='array_'+df['Group'].astype(str))
   .groupby('Group')['ID'].apply(list).to_dict()
)
```

output:

```
{'array_1': [3645390, 3678122],
 'array_2': [3615370, 3371122, 3645590],
 'array_3': [3778682, 3125140, 3578772]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create a new list for every array, you can much more easily store them in a dictionary and access them using `array[1]`, `array[2]` and so on. This is what an implementation would look like:

```
array = {}
for group in df.Group.drop_duplicates().tolist():
    array[group] = df[df.Group == group, 'ID']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
>>> {k: list(v) for k, v in df.groupby('Group')['ID']}
{1: [3645390, 3678122], 2: [3615370, 3371122, 3645590], 3: [3778682, 3125140, 3578772]}
>>>
```

But if you are fine with series, just use:

```
>>> dict(tuple(df.groupby('Group')['ID']))
{1: 0    3645390
1    3678122
Name: ID, dtype: int64, 2: 2    3615370
3    3371122
4    3645590
Name: ID, dtype: int64, 3: 5    3778682
6    3125140
7    3578772
Name: ID, dtype: int64}
>>>
```